# Java script: Recursively walk the Dom for an associated HTML file and print the type of elements encountered

Tags: javascript, html, dom, recursion

I want to write a simple JavaScript program that will recursively walk the
DOM for an associated HTML file and print the types of the elements encountered
(embedded data need not be printed), indented to reflect the hierarchical nature of the HTML document.

I don't know what's wrong with my code but the recursive part does not give the right output.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Output

```
Top 3 Channel 3 Thai actresses: 

    1.Yaya Urassaya
    2.Kimberly Ann Voltemas
    3.Margie Rasri Balenciaga

[object Text], nodeName: #text, nodeType: 3, innerHTML: undefined
[object Text], nodeName: #text, nodeType: 3, innerHTML: undefined
[object HTMLLIElement], nodeName: LI, nodeType: 1, innerHTML: Yaya Urassaya
[object Text], nodeName: #text, nodeType: 3, innerHTML: undefined
[object Text], nodeName: #text, nodeType: 3, innerHTML: undefined
[object HTMLLIElement], nodeName: LI, nodeType: 1, innerHTML: Kimberly Ann Voltemas
[object Text], nodeName: #text, nodeType: 3, innerHTML: undefined
[object Text], nodeName: #text, nodeType: 3, innerHTML: undefined
[object HTMLLIElement], nodeName: LI, nodeType: 1, innerHTML: Margie Rasri Balenciaga
[object Text], nodeName: #text, nodeType: 3, innerHTML: undefined
```

Correct Output

```
Top 3 Channel 3 Thai actresses: 

    1.Yaya Urassaya
    2.Kimberly Ann Voltemas
    3.Margie Rasri Balenciaga

[object Text], nodeName: #text, nodeType: 3, innerHTML: undefined
[object HTMLLIElement], nodeName: LI, nodeType: 1, innerHTML: Yaya Urassaya
[object Text], nodeName: #text, nodeType: 3, innerHTML: undefined
[object HTMLLIElement], nodeName: LI, nodeType: 1, innerHTML: Kimberly Ann Voltemas
[object Text], nodeName: #text, nodeType: 3, innerHTML: undefined
[object HTMLLIElement], nodeName: LI, nodeType: 1, innerHTML: Margie Rasri Balenciaga
[object Text], nodeName: #text, nodeType: 3, innerHTML: undefined
```

My HTML file

```
    <!doctype html>
       <HTML>
       <HEAD>
       </HEAD>
       <BODY>
           <P> Top 3 Channel 3 Thai actresses: </P>
           <ol>
           <li>Yaya Urassaya</li>
           <li>Kimberly Ann Voltemas</li>
           <li>Margie Rasri Balenciaga</li>
           </ol> 
         <div id="idDiv"></div>
         <script type="text/javascript" 
          src="A3Q4.js"> 
         </script>
      <BODY>
      </HTML>
```

My Javascript file

```
 var element = document.getElementById("idDiv");

 function printNodeInfo(node) 
 {
   element.innerHTML += node;
   element.innerHTML += ", nodeName: " + node.nodeName;
   element.innerHTML += ", nodeType: " + node.nodeType;
   element.innerHTML += ", innerHTML: " + node.innerHTML;
   element.innerHTML += "<br>";
 }

 // Get a handle of the ordered-list node.
 var orderedlistNode = document.getElementsByTagName("ol")[0];
 theDOMElementWalker(orderedlistNode);

 function theDOMElementWalker(node) 
 {
   if (node.nodeType == 1) 
   { 
      node = node.firstChild;

      while (node) 
      {
        theDOMElementWalker(node);
        printNodeInfo(node);
        node = node.nextSibling;
      }
   }
 }
 element.innerHTML += "<br>";
```

Comment: You could use the built-in TreeWalker class https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, even though it is not visible, there could be empty text nodes between elements in the dom tree, take a markup like `<div> <span>content</span></div>`, now between the `div` and `span` opening there is a space, which will create a text node in the dom tree, so you can to exclude the text node if it is empty to get your expected result.

```js
var element = document.getElementById("idDiv");

function printNodeInfo(node) {
  if (node.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE && !node.nodeValue.trim()) {
    return;
  }
  element.innerHTML += node;
  element.innerHTML += ", nodeName: " + node.nodeName;
  element.innerHTML += ", nodeType: " + node.nodeType;
  element.innerHTML += ", innerHTML: " + node.innerHTML;
  element.innerHTML += "<br>";
}

// Get a handle of the ordered-list node.
var orderedlistNode = document.getElementsByTagName("ol")[0];
theDOMElementWalker(orderedlistNode);

function theDOMElementWalker(node) {
  if (node.nodeType == 1) {
    node = node.firstChild;

    while (node) {
      theDOMElementWalker(node);
      printNodeInfo(node);
      node = node.nextSibling;
    }
  }
}
element.innerHTML += "<br>";
```

```html
<P>Top 3 Channel 3 Thai actresses:</P>
<ol>
  <li>Yaya Urassaya</li>
  <li>Kimberly Ann Voltemas</li>
  <li>Margie Rasri Balenciaga</li>
</ol>
<div id="idDiv"></div>
```